# dropdown List Hidden by slider html

Tags: html, css, slider

I have a slick slider with dropdown list, when I open the list, it's hidden by the slider. I checked the slick.css and I found this:

```js
$('.variable-width').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 6,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.slider {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.slider {
  height: 80px;
}

.slider p {
  background: #fff;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h2>Variable Width</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider variable-width">
    <div style="width: 200px; color:red">
      <span>
              <a class='dropdown-button btn white clickDrop' ng-click="clickS()"
                data-activates='dropdownSkill' style="width: 295px">Drop Me!</a>
                            <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
              <div id='dropdownSkill' class='dropdown-content'>
                  <input class="inputDropdown" ng-model="skillValue"    style="margin-left: 5px">
                  <ul class="" style="width: 300px" ng-repeat="skill in skillsFilter | filter: skillValue">
                  <li ng-click="selectSkill(skill.SKILLID)" ng-model="skill.SKILLID">alyssa</li>
                   <li ng-click="selectSkill(skill.SKILLID)" ng-model="skill.SKILLID">mel</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
            </span>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 200px;">
      <p>200</p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 75px;">
      <p>75</p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 300px;">
      <p>300</p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 225px;">
      <p>225</p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 175px;">
      <p>175</p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100px;">
      <p>100</p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 200px;">
      <p>200</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

but when I remove the overflow, all slick-slide are shown like this: 
[image]
I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/memvovkz/150/

Can someone help me please
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Descendent elements will always be clipped by the element with `overflow: hidden`. Even elements with `position: fixed`.

You can move dropdown from slider, set it position fixed or absolute. After that onclick on "DROP ME!" you set position of dropdown list where you need and show it.

To get right position you can use offset of "DROP ME"